# Leaflet draw/filter

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I have loaded a geoJSON layer that is a features collection into a leaflet map. I want to draw a rectangle on the map and I want all of the features intersecting the rectangle to be selected while features outside the rectangle disappear. Could someone point me to what I need to accomplish this task?

Comment: this is a broad question. Have you checked out Leaflet Draw and Turf.js? One approach, on DrawCreated you could intersect with Turf, e.g. Turf intersect https://github.com/Turfjs/turf/tree/master/packages/turf-intersect

Comment: I am new to web maps, I was just looking for some direction. I can't believe leaflet does not have a plugin that selects features within an area. I am trying to make an aerial photo catalog that can be referenced to find aerial photos. People draw a rectangle on the map and a list of aerial photos along with their footprints are retrieved from the geoJSON layer. Straightforward yet few people share how they are doing it

Answer (score 1):

I do this with points, I create a leaflet map with my GeoJSON, and include TURF. I use the DRAW plugin, I draw a polygon and use turf to select the points inside, this creates the JSON you want to parse. You can add the selection JSON back in as the new layer and remove the old layer giving you the impression everything outside the selection is gone. My code guts..

```
         rectangle: {
            shapeOptions: {
                color: 'blue'
            }
        },
        marker: false
    },
    edit: {
        featureGroup: featureGroup   //the new polygon/rectangle
    }
};

var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw(options);
map.addControl(drawControl);    

    map.on('draw:created', function (e) {
        featureGroup.clearLayers();  //clears prior selection polygon
        layer = e.layer;
        featureGroup.addLayer(layer);
        GetSelection(featureGroup);
    });

function GetSelection(layer){

    var shape2 = allPoints.toGeoJSON()
    var ptsWithin2 = turf.within(shape2, layer.toGeoJSON());

        alert('Found ' + ptsWithin2.features.length + ' features'); 
        alert("results "+JSON.stringify(ptsWithin2));
};
```

Within may not be the turf option in your case but  `var intersection = turf.intersect(poly1, poly2);` maybe the better fit.

This may also help: [Intersecting FeatureCollections in turf.js?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129750/intersecting-featurecollections-in-turf-js)